# jQuery autcomplete not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete but it is not working.

When loading it the following way it does work:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-autocomplete', '',array('jquery-ui-widget', 'jquery-ui-position'), '1.8.6');
```

However when loading the full jquery-ui downloaded from the website:

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );

wp_register_script('jquery', (COLLABPRESS_PLUGIN_URL . 'includes/js/jquery-1.9.1.js'), false, '1.9.1');
wp_register_script('jquery-ui-core', (COLLABPRESS_PLUGIN_URL . 'includes/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js'), array('jquery'), '1.10.3', 1 );

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
```

It does not work..
What am I missing here?
There should be no different here, right?

All other elements, such as calendar and slider, do work.

UPDATE:
The plugin was loading a jQuery-ui theme, removing this results in the following:
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbymQ.png
It thus does seem to work.

However, adding any jquery-ui theme will result in the auto-complete not to be working at all anymore? Doesn't matter what version. Unless I use the first method mentioned above to include it, than it works no matter what jquer-ui style I use.

UPDATE:
It seems that the div in which the results are displayed is automatically set to `display:none`. 
I also noticed when including both methods at the same time, it does work but when I rollover the selection menu quickly disappears (this is expected due to the multiple instances of auto complete).

I looked online for similar issues with the `display:none` but non of the found answers are appliable. Any pointers?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that these paths are correct? I mean does COLLABPRESS_PLUGIN_URL ends with '/' character for example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes paths are surely correct; when I output `COLLABPRESS_PLUGIN_URL` I receive the full path including trailing `/`.

Comment: OK. And are there any errors/warnings in your browsers JS console?

Comment: No the only error available is an image that cannot be found, however this error is always present regardless of what way I load the scripts.

Comment: I have updated the question, it seems that it is working.. but the jQuery-ui Theme's are causing it to malfunction.